# How to apply existing Label in Gmail filter?

Tags: gmail-filters, gmail-labels

How to apply existing label as my search criteria in my old emails in `Filters and Blocked Addresses` when creating a new filter?

I need to filter my emails by time, sender and by is:unread status etc. and I already created a label with all of those options.

I know the `Also apply filter to matching conversations` option and I will enable it as soon as I can filter emails with my `old_label`. If I enter my label name in `Includes the words` it doesn't work. Wouldn't it be easier for us that Google adds `Includes this label` filter option. Is there a workaround?

As you can see, there is no label option criteria in `Filter and Blocked Addresses`. Of course I can filter it in my inbox in a search field by searching for `label:old_label`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found a solution [here](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6579). The trick was to click this little arrow. But you can't forward old messages by filter, only the new ones.
[image]

[image]

[image]

And then create a filter with new options or with your label.